# Hibernate inner join using hql

Tags: hibernate, inner-join

I am new to Hibernate.  I have two tables, e.g., `student` and `phone number` and these two tables have a common column, `student id`.
I want to do an inner join with these two tables using Hibernate hql.

**student.java**

```
{
   private int id;   
   private String name;   
}
```

**phone.java**

```
{
   private int pid;
   private int sid;  //same id in student.java 
   private int phone_number;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/) again. You're not supposed to have the ID of the student in the Phone entity. Rather, you're supposed to have an association between both entities: a Phone belongs to a Student:

```
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student owner;
}
```

Only then will you be able to use joins:

```
// selects all the phones belonging to the students named 'John'
select phone from Phone phone where phone.owner.name = 'John'
```

Comment: ok thanks..how can i will perform the same thing  more than two tables ??

Comment: Of course you can: where phone.owner.school.country.name = 'USA' for example. This is explained in the excellent Hibernate documentation. Read it.

Comment: ok thanks..then how can we iterate the query results for a many to many relationships in hibernate ..I will tried a lot.But I can't achieving it.

Comment: this is my query                                                String hql = "select e.employee_id,m.meeting_id from Employee e join e.meetings m";                                                         
        query = session.createQuery(hql);

Comment: This query returns a `List<Object[]>`. Each Object[] contains the employee ID as first element, and the meeting ID as second element.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet...can you please provide an example this query:  String hql = "select e.employee_id,m.meeting_id from Employee e join e.meetings m"

Comment: You don't know how to iterate a List? And you're using Hibernate? Anyway, here it goes: `List<Object[]> list = query.list(); for (Object[] row : list) {Long employeeId = (Long) row[0]; Long meetingId = row[1]; // TODO do something with these IDs }`

Comment: Hi JB Nizet I have one more doubt.How can I iterate the same List<Object[]> in a struts2 jsp page.Can you help me please.

Comment: This is the code am tryed.but i can't achieved that.     <s:iterator value="row">  
            <s:property value="row[0]" />  
            <s:property value="row[1]" />  
     </s:iterator>

Comment: This is the code am tryed.but I can't achieved that.     <s:iterator value="row">  
            <s:property value="row[0]" />  
            <s:property value="row[1]" /> </iterator>

Answer (score 3):

With the two classes like that hibernate is unaware of the association that makes life difficult. What would be normal is to make the sid in the phone class an actual Student object so hibernate is aware of the association. e.g.

```
class Phone {
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "sid")
    private Student student;
}
```

having done this then you can do a simple HQL join e.g.

```
FROM Phone p
JOIN p.student s
```

Alternatively if there is some reason you want the raw ID in the object then you can use a "theta join" where you explicitly specify the association like a normal SQL Join. E.g.

```
FROM Phone p, Student s
WHERE p.sid = s.id
```

Answer (score -3):

Please find below the HQL:

SELECT * FROM student ST INNER JOIN phonenumber PN ON ST.id = PN.id where ST.Name='XXXX'

Comment: i ma getting this error :org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 91